# Print a report on how Windows 10 services are configured?

Tags: windows-10, services, configuration-managment

I'm in the middle of taming a new machine.

In the course of that I've installed a handful of things which add services... but I've also disabled a large number of M$ crapware/intrusionware/irrelevant services.

Is there any way of producing a report of what you see in the "Services" dialog...? In the form of a PDF or .xls file or something? The only thing I can think of doing at the moment is a screenshot!  But surely there must be a data table of some kind buried deep in the bowels of W10 ...

In a more general sense, I'm wondering if it's possible to produce reports on all/most of the configuration settings of W10? This could come in useful for all sorts of Sys Admin type purposes.

Comment: Your more general question is too broad. Lots of reporting is possible, but you need to be more specific about what you want.

Comment: @DavidPostill Ok, well, put it like this: to explore dysfunctionality, or just differences of apparent functioning, from one machine to the next, I'd like to be able to explore many different "leads".   You say "lots of reporting is possible", so I suppose I need to find an intro to such reporting.

Comment: There isn't really an into. There are a lot of useful command line tools though. Start with https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html. And see also [sysinternals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) and [nirsoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/) for additional tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Is there any way of producing a report of what you see in the "Services" dialog?

Yes.

In a `cmd` shell, run the following `sc` command:

```
sc query state= all
```

To save the output in a file:

```
sc query state= all > sevice_report.txt
```

Example output:

```
SERVICE_NAME: !SASCORE
DISPLAY_NAME: SAS Core Service
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS  
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING 
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

SERVICE_NAME: ACDaemon
DISPLAY_NAME: ArcSoft Connect Daemon
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS  
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED 
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 1077  (0x435)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

SERVICE_NAME: AdobeARMservice
DISPLAY_NAME: Adobe Acrobat Update Service
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS  
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING 
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

SERVICE_NAME: AdobeFlashPlayerUpdateSvc
DISPLAY_NAME: Adobe Flash Player Update Service
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS  
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED 
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 1077  (0x435)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
...
```

---

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [SC - Service Control - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/sc.html)

Comment: Thanks... I tried this but it didn't seem to work: my .txt file says "[SC] EnumQueryServicesStatus:OpenService FAILED 1060: The specified service does not exist as an installed service."  I tried this with an "elevated prompt" but got the same...

Comment: @mikerodent Make sure you have a space after `state=` otherwise you will get that error.

Comment: Tx, got there in the end!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Powershell get-service commandlet. It's output can of course be piped to a text file.

Comment: Oh I see... just go and literally type "get-service".  Thanks. Have (clearly) no knowledge whatsoever of Powershell!